# Music managing software delete lower quality duplicates

Tags: itunes, music, deduplication, music-management

Until the end of the last year I was one of the few people who used Google Play Music, and as it was discontinued, I downloaded all my music using Google Takeout. Now I have almost all of my songs in two versions, the one I uploaded to Google Play Music in the first place, and the one I downloaded with Takeout. Some of the ones I downloaded have higher quality than the ones I uploaded, but not all of them do. Now I imported all of the files into iTunes, and of cause have everything duplicated.
Now to the question: Is there any way to automatically delete the lower quality file? I thought maybe iTunes would have the possibility, but so far I didn't find it. Is there such a possibility?

Anything that works is appreciated, even if it is another programme, it doesn't have to be iTunes. In fact, I don't like iTunes that much, but I tried many other organising programmes like MusicBee, and so far I didn't find anything that I really liked.

I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3293239?answerId=25763036022#25763036022) post that describes a script that chooses which file to keep using the file size, but that assumes that the larger one is the one with higher quality, which is not always the case. And another problem is, that the files which contain the same song don't always have the same file name.

So a summary of what (I think) I need:

A possibility to find a duplicate song in a file system (sturctured by my iTunes library) and compare all the found duplicates to delete all but the one with the highest quality.

---

**EDIT:** This question was closed due to being off topic because I wanted advice for some kind of software which is not the way this forum works. So let me rephrase the goal of what I want to achieve either by a programme **or** by a script: I'd like to compare an audio file to multiple other audiofiles which may or may not contain the same song, and then objectively determine the one with the highest quality. As pointed out by [Ярослав Рахматуллин](https://superuser.com/users/86129/%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD) there are criteria by which such an objective comparison can be made, and there are probably more he (and I) did not think of yet.

Comment: I thought higher quality is almost always the same as bigger file size. I have an idea about how to solve your problem, but your observation about "bigger does not mean better" is confusing. How do you measure/score highest quality then? Mp3 bitrate? Are the files encoded with different formats? Do you have a preference? My idea is to identify the files / songs using music-brains audio fingerprinting, but you need to describe why bigger is not better in your case. Please update your question.

Comment: I see your point, but there are some cases where a larger file is not the better one. As you already mentioned, bitrate is also important. But sometimes I have files that don't have a good quality but still are quite large, e.g. some CD rips, probably because of noise in the background of the audio track. In this case I'd rather keep the smaller file with better quality than the larger one with lower quality. I also thought about audio fingerprinting, but I don't know how.

Comment: Ok, I would say the objective quality of an audio file depends on the the sampling-rate of the sound and the range of recorded frequencies (amplitude). Some files may have a larger file-size and otherwise equal sampling rate, and record only-up-to e.g 12000 HZ, while others may be smaller and record up-to 18000 HZ. The amplitude (for example 12k vs 18k) variation largely depends on the source of the original material, and is the dominant factor for perceived quality. I don't work with music, so I can't point you to a ready-made tool which can analyze this for you. iTunes, definitely will not.

Comment: I find this question to be genuinely interesting and even possible to answer without all the references to google and apple or other commercial products. I think it was prematurely closed, but without doubt could have been phrased differently. "We" don't generally care about services or commercial applications on superuser, but I do see an interesting question here. Perhaps the author does not share my opinion (they may want a commercial tool), but I think the answer can be realized in the form of a 200-400 lines long script and is really a cool problem to solve.

Comment: Figuring out the quality of sound files is for sure not off-topic on superuser, given we can agree on what quality means objectively. it is also not off-topic to elucidate open source tools for achieving this purpose.

Comment: I completely agree with you that I think this question was closed way to early, but until now I didn't think of a way to rephrase it in a way that it wouldn't be closed again. I don't need a full programme, some code would do it as well, as long as it is commented in a way that I understand what it does. I'm not that familiar with coding, so some explanation is in all means necessary. If iTunes doesn't do it, that is no problem at all, it is only the tool I used to get all my unsorted mp3s into some sort of ordered structure. So if somebody is about to come up with some sort of script,

Comment: it would be a practicable solution as well. I don't have the option to use a Mac though, so it would need to be either windows or linux compatible. Now to the quality measurement: what you pointed out is in my opinion a very logical way to measure quality. After some further research I found a tool called [SimilarityApp] (https://www.similarityapp.com/) that does do kind of what I need, but for what it does it is quite expensive. It probably should be possible for someone with a little coding experience to implement a script that does what I need, and probably many people would appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120493/discussion-between-darkdiamond-and--).